# how to display more than 1 number in a label

Tags: vb.net, random

why does & not create a space between the two numbers being displayed?

'random generates lottery numbers

```
    Dim Lotto As New Random
    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intNum3 As Integer
    Dim intNum4 As Integer
    Dim intNum5 As Integer
    Dim IntNum6 As Integer
    Dim IntTotal As Integer

    intNum1 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)
    intNum2 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)
    intNum3 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)
    intNum4 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)
    intNum5 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)
    IntNum6 = Lotto.Next(1, 54)

    'winning lotto numbers
    IntTotal = intNum1 & intNum2 & intNum3
    lblLottoNum.Text = IntTotal.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `IntTotal` variable, instead just put spaces between the individual numbers themselves, like this:

```
lblLottoNum.Text = intNum1.ToString() & " " & intNum2.ToString() & _
    " " & intNum3.ToString()
```

Comment: @user2985851 - if you feel this answer helped you, then please accept the answer and/or up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This allows you to format the string you want and is easy to read:

for example you could do this:

```
lblLottoNum.Text = String.Format("The numbers are: {0}, {1} and {2}", intNum1, intNum2, intNum3)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
lblLottoNum.Text = intNum1.ToString() & " " & intNum2.ToString() & " " & intNum3.ToString()
```